# Get Facebook public profile information

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am wondering if you can get the public profile information of the user if they don't authorize your app. I am using Facebook login inside a page tab and a canvas page. Is there a way to get the user Facebook ID if they don't accept the login permission dialog? I know if i am able to find you the userid i can fetch the public profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two questions in 1 question:

Can I get public information without Facebook login:
Yes, that is possible: You can use the Graph explorer to check that out https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

You will get basic information, like name, first_name, gender and locale

Question 2: Can I get the Facebook ID without FB login:
It's not possible (anymore). You must have a valid session (e.g. with a Facebook login) in order to get a facebook user id.